# Remove preconfigured VSCode buttons on touch bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm trying to remove some buttons on the touch bar when using VSCode. (In my case, I'd like to keep the previous/next file buttons but to remove debugger ones.)

I saw on VSCode settings that I can remove buttons one by one:
"**Keyboard › Touchbar: Ignored**
A set of identifiers for entries in the touchbar that should not show up (for example `workbench.action.navigateBack`)."

However, I don't know where to find the name of the identifiers.
Do you know what are the identifiers mentioned or where to find them?

Thanks for your help,

[EDIT]
I finally found these identifiers. You can find them in Code => preferences => keyboard shortcuts and there are under the name of the different commands.

For information, the identifiers preconfigured are:
- workbench.action.navigateBack
- workbench.action.navigateForward
- workbench.action.debug.start
- workbench.action.debug.run

Comment: I don't have this setting, so you must have an extension I that don't have. Look in the docs of that extension

Comment: Thanks @rioV8.
I think it's not an extension. It's in the vscode application (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/services/keybinding/electron-browser/keybinding.contribution.ts). You should be able to find it in Application/keyboard settings.

Comment: Maybe I don't have it because I don't use macOS.

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can see it in the link I sent you in the precedent comment @rioV8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remi is correct. You can disable the default vscode touchbar buttons by going to Settings => Keyboard > Touchbar: Ignored and then then adding

- workbench.action.navigateBack
- workbench.action.navigateForward
- workbench.action.debug.start
- workbench.action.debug.run

Additionally, you can use something like [Nasc VSCode Touchbar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felipe.nasc-touchbar) to extend your touchbar.

Original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146950/11842709