# Is there a way to disable the function keys shortcuts in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just got a new MacBook Pro with the which has a *touch bar*. Not sure what Apple was thinking, but this is one of the worst things ever.

Is there a way to disable the *function keys* shortcuts/commands in VS Code? Each time I'm coding I keep touching the touch bar - its annoying.

Comment: Are you talking about the key `fn` or the keys `f1`, `f2` etc.?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52593251/1787868

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect

Comment: [*As a side note*] There is also an option to always show the *function keys* in the Touch Bar for specific apps. It is described in the "Show the function keys" paragraph on the following Apple documentation page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240