# Mac touchBar in vscode doesn't have a toggle breakpoint key

Tags: visual-studio-code, breakpoints, macbookpro-touch-bar

Thank you for the best project vscode first .

I use the vscode on Mac,and my computer is enable the touchBar App contral option in keyboard settings.
When I code or debug,the touchBar doesn't have a toggle breakpoint key.
Now it's like this [editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHHzQ.png)
[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIzAn.jpg)

Computer info :MacBook Pro a1990

OS: macOs 14.2 (23C64)

vscode info:

Version: 1.85.1 (Universal)

Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2

Date: 2023-12-13T09:48:06.308Z (21 hrs ago)

Electron: 25.9.7

ElectronBuildId: 25551756

Chromium: 114.0.5735.289

Node.js: 18.15.0

V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0

OS: Darwin x64 23.2.0

I tried to find an option to config this, but I can't find.
So I hope it's can be option to configure or provide it in default,it will be like this :
[editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipCYg.png)
[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wmeq.png)

Comment: This... probably should be a feature request (I guess?) on the VS Code repository. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues I don't think we will be able to help with this

Comment: This looks like a feature request in VS Code

Comment: ok, when i have this thought , i want make a issues , but i'm not sure it doesn't have config , so i come here and make this question . but anyway  thank you for response.
I'll make a feature request in github .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the touch bar in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060436/how-to-customize-the-touch-bar-in-visual-studio-code)